# makefile: symbol(s) not found for architecture

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm trying to solve an issue with makefile.

I have a main.cpp and then addOn.cpp and addOn.hpp.
I'm just trying to do the simple makefile to compile this.

I have:

```
    main: Main.o Log.o
        g++ -o main Main.o Log.o

    Main.o: main.cpp  Log.hpp
        g++ -c main.cpp

    Log.o: Log.cpp Log.hpp
        g++ -c Log.cpp
```

But keep getting:

```
    $ make
    g++ -c main.cpp
    g++ -c Log.cpp
    g++ -o main Main.o Log.o
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "Log::~Log()", referenced from:
          _main in Main.o
      "Log::overallVerboseLvl", referenced from:
          Log::setLevel(int)  in Log.o
          Log::Log()   in Log.o
          Log::Log()   in Log.o
          Log::operator<<(char const*)in Log.o
      "Log::fileName", referenced from:
          Log::setFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in Log.o
          Log::Log(int)in Log.o
          Log::Log(int)in Log.o
          Log::Log()   in Log.o
          Log::Log()   in Log.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Here are the files
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Log.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Log::setFile("output.log"); 
    Log(Log::LEVEL_INF) << "out and up..."; 
    Log::setLevel(Log::LEVEL_INF); 
    Log(Log::LEVEL_INF) << "another line"; 
    Log(Log::LEVEL_ERR) << "now a number: " << 13; 
    Log(Log::LEVEL_DBG) << "I shall not pass";
    return 0;
}
```

Log.hpp

```
#ifndef log_Log_hpp
#define log_Log_hpp
#include <string.h>

class Log{
    private:
        static std::string fileName;
        static int overallVerboseLvl;
        int messageVerboseLvl;
    public:
    static const int LEVEL_INF;
    static const int LEVEL_ERR;
    static const int LEVEL_DBG;

    Log(int verboseLvl);
    Log();
    ~Log();
    std::ostream& operator<<(char const*);
    static void setFile(std::string file);
    static void setLevel(int level);

};


#endif
```

Log.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Log.hpp"

const int Log::LEVEL_INF = 0;
const int Log::LEVEL_ERR = 1;
const int Log::LEVEL_DBG = 2;

void Log::setLevel(int level){
    Log::overallVerboseLvl = level;
}

void Log::setFile(std::string fileName ){
    Log::fileName = fileName;
}

Log::Log(){
    Log::fileName = "";
    Log::overallVerboseLvl = Log::LEVEL_DBG;
}

Log::Log(int verboseLvl){
    Log::fileName = "";
    Log::messageVerboseLvl = verboseLvl;
}

std::ostream& Log::operator<<(char const* text){
    if (Log::overallVerboseLvl >= Log::messageVerboseLvl) {
        std::cout << text;
    }     
    return std::cout;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us your source files?

Comment: I notice a file `Log.o` mentioned in the error output.  Is this in your makefile, too?

Comment: Is there a file called Log.cpp too? Have you got two makefiles in the same directory?

Comment: Do I gather correctly that the commands `make Main.o` and `make addOn.o` each seem to work correctly, and that only `make main` yields error messages?

Comment: In addOn.cpp, have you provided implementations for ~addOn, overallVerboseLvl, and filename?

Comment: @gbulmer The thing about Log was that I was changing from Log to addOn.

Comment: @templatetypedef here they are

Comment: @thb I think so, I think now the log shows this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't defined the destructor or the missing static variables. Add one of these:

```
Log::~Log() {
}
```

The static variables part is kind of unintuitive. You've declared them, but haven't defined them. You can think of it like this - all the compiler knows is that you want to be able to use those variables. But say you include `Log.h` 100 times. You wouldn't want the compiler to create 100 copies of the same variables. So you have to give it a place to actually instantiate them. In your `Log.cpp` file, do this:

```
// Note, no 'static' keyword needed (or allowed).
std::string Log::fileName;
int Log::overallVerboseLvl;
```

Answer (score 3):

have a clean target, run make clean command and then try make. I think you may have some .o files from a previous compilation on different operating system

```
clean:
     <TAB> rm *.o
```

Comment: I did this, and got the result that is now on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined those things the linker is complaining about.  You have declared ~Log() but there's no such method in Log.cpp.  Similiarly, the static variables `filename` and `overallVerboseLvl` must be defined in Log.cpp.